# Tkinter modern dialogue box suddenly not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I use the following code to show dialogue boxes:

```
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import messagebox
messagebox.showerror(title='xx', message='xxx')
```

And I use PyInstaller to compile into exe. Today I found out that the modern themed dialogue box is no longer there. I downloaded the exe binary built a month ago, the dialogue box are modern themed, however, the one I just built are no longer. The code relevant to the box are exactly the same, and I am running on exactly the same system. I do not understand where the issue could be.

Here is an example of modern and old:

Old:
[image]

New: [image]

As you can see, the buttons are completely different.

Both binaries are built with Python 3.9.8 and latest development build of PyInstaller

Comment: doesn't seem like they are the same box, the "old" one is just a `.showerror` and the "new" one is a `.askokcancel` box. You also haven't provided the code for the "new" box, so how are we supposed to know that they have the same code? Also the boxes have completely different text and have been adapted to that

Comment: @Matiiss the code used are already given. All I did was to change the text. It behaves exactly same no matter which type of box I used. I have tried all 4. If you know Tkinter on python well enough, you will know that all these boxes calls the same underlying function, just changes the buttons and icons.

Comment: well, then what issue are you having? there is no reason without a change for the functions to suddenly stop executing correctly. If you just change text while calling the same exact function then the box should be the same just with different text. The dialogs you have provide are produced by different functions. Yes they just provide different arguments to the private `_show` function but those shouldn't change. the "old" box is created using `showerror` and the "new" box is created using `askyesno`

Comment: @Matiiss I found out myself and answered it below. It was indeed not my code issue, but more of a python issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it myself after discussing with PyInstaller maintainer. (See here: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/discussions/6366)

The problem is that in Python 3.9.8 they dropped a Windows dependency that enables the modern UI support. This was a change made from 3.9.7 to 3.9.8. To work around this, you have to specify your own manifest file and add the following content into it:

```
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" language="*" processorArchitecture="*" version="6.0.0.0" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"/>
      <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
```

Update:
This is fixed in latest PyInstaller development build: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/6367